# Subsetting a vector using a list of sequences in R

Tags: r, list, vector, subset, sequence

I have a character vector that contains textual data which I can subset by selecting individual lines. The eventual goal is to store different sequences of the vector as independent variables or element of a list. I am able to do this using a simple loop, but I don't succeed in subsetting a character vector by a list of sequences.

See the following example:

```
Text<-scan("~/Desktop/Lorem Ipsum.txt", what="character", sep="\n")

 [1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "                                                                          
 [2] "consectetur adipiscing elit,"                                                                          
 [3] "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "                                                                     
 [4] "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."                                                                     
 [5] "Ut enim ad minim veniam, "                                                                             
 [6] "quis nostrud exercitation "                                                                            
 [7] "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."                                              
 [8] "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
 [9] "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,"                                                       
[10] "sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

The normal way of subsetting the vector would be `text[1:4]`, returning

```
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "      
[2] "consectetur adipiscing elit,"    
[3] "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "
[4] "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

In a list I have stored sequences of numbers that represent different sets of lines in the vector.

`Sentence.numbers<-c(1:4, 5:7, 8, 9:10).`

Now I would like to subset all the numbers that make up the different sentences at once and store them in a list for further analysis.

I used `Text[Sentence.numbers]`, but the error message is "invalid index type 'list'".

Is there a way to use a list of values to subset?

Comment: That error means `Sentence.numbers` is a list instead of a vector. Did you use `list` instead of `c`? You can convert with `unlist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up `Sentence.numbers` as a list and then use `lapply` -

```
Sentence.numbers <- list(1:4, 5:7, 8, 9:10)

lapply(Sentence.numbers, function(x) Text[x])
```

Here's an example -

```
lapply(Sentence.numbers, function(x) letters[x])

[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "e" "f" "g"

[[3]]
[1] "h"

[[4]]
[1] "i" "j"
```

Comment: Or, you know, just not make it a list in the first place, or `unlist`ing it...

Comment: *" I would like to subset all the numbers that make up the different sentences at once and store them in a list for further analysis"* - My understanding is that `Sentence.numbers` is already a list and OP made a mistake by using `c` in the post. Anyways every element in that list combines different sentences from `Text` and that's what OP wants. Use of `lapply` seems correct to me till OP clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I worked the original data around so that I can simply use the lapply-command. All solved now.